# Invoke a website button from iOS app

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, http, ios9

Will I able to invoke a button action ( HTTP Post/Get) through swift? I searched few posts and I am able to retrieve the contents from a web page. But I am not able to post anything. Say, web page has a login screen and the user needs to enter user name and password and click submit. How do I do this? note: The website I am using doesnt use URL parameters

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Is the website you're trying to access your own site? (i.e. do you have control over how it works?)

Comment: no. I am trying to access corporate outlook web mail. Trying to create a mail client app

Comment: Try looking a little deeper into how Outlook handles the information. Is it authenticated through a PHP script? What happens when the user clicks submit?